# jQuery pagination with <p> tag displays all pages in a single page if it has some other tag inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I am using jquery pagination, but its not working if it has some other tag inside.

Here is my code:

```
    <head>
    <link href="simplePagination.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    var items = $(".content");
    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 1;
    items.slice(perPage).hide();
    $("#pagination").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
    var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
    var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
    items.hide();
    items.slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="pagination"></div>
    <p class="content">
    <table><tr>Window0</tr></table></p> //this code is working 
if it doesn't have the table and 
div tag inside, but in my original its mandatory for me to have this table tag and div tag
    <p class="content"><div>Window1</div></p>
    <p class="content">Window2</p>
    <p class="content">Window3</p>
    <p class="content">Window4</p>
    </body>
```

All the plugins of pagination is available here.[https://github.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js](http://github.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js)

See my comment line i have given in my code, there is the problem. Help me to resolve this.

Comment: You want to have a `table` inside your pagination `div`? Or the pagination `div` inside the `table`?

Comment: @HugoSousa i want to have table inside pagination div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your markup. `p` tags aren't meant to contain other block-level elements like you're doing, [but only "phrasing" elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html). Use a `div` as your `.content` element and then nest appropriately within it, and everything works fine. **([DEMO](http://jsbin.com/guride/1))**

```
<div id="pagination"></div>
<div class="content"><table><tr><td>Window0</td></tr></table></div>
<div class="content"><div>Window1</div></div>
<div class="content">Window2</div>
<div class="content">Window3</div>
<div class="content">Window4</div>
```

Also in the future, it would be helpful to specify the behavior you're actually seeing, rather than "not working"--that doesn't help anybody troubleshoot.

Comment: thank you so much... its works fine... and will keep in mind about specifying title. thanks for that suggestion too... :-)